# SQL Server: Use either AND or OR based on conditional in the where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which is filtering a set of data based on a group of conditional parameters.

```
@Parameter1 int = null,
@Parameter2 int = null,
@Parameter3 int = null,
@Parameter4 int = null,
@Parameter5 int = null,
@UseOR bit = False

Select * 
From Table
Where 
    (@Parameter1 Is Null Or Column1 = @Parameter1) And
    (@Parameter2 Is Null Or Column2 = @Parameter2) And
    (@Parameter3 Is Null Or Column3 = @Parameter3) And
    (@Parameter4 Is Null Or Column4 = @Parameter4) And
    (@Parameter5 Is Null Or Column5 = @Parameter5)
```

But then for some users, two of the columns (Column3 and Column4) need to be joined with OR instead of AND.

This is where the `@UseOR` parameter comes in. So only for some users (which will be defined in the application code), the query should have an OR between column 3 and 4, e.g:

```
Select * 
From Table
Where 
        (@Parameter1 Is Null Or Column1 = @Parameter1) And
        (@Parameter2 Is Null Or Column2 = @Parameter2) And
        (@Parameter3 Is Null Or Column3 = @Parameter3) OR
        (@Parameter4 Is Null Or Column4 = @Parameter4) And
        (@Parameter5 Is Null Or Column5 = @Parameter5)
```

And for the others, it will be like the original. I am not sure if it is possible to change the `AND` to `OR` based on if the `@UseOR` is true. In my mind, it would nice to have something like this:

```
Select * 
From Table
Where 
    (@Parameter1 Is Null Or Column1 = @Parameter1) And
    (@Parameter2 Is Null Or Column2 = @Parameter2) And
    (@Parameter3 Is Null Or Column3 = @Parameter3) IIF(@UseOR = True, OR, AND)
    (@Parameter4 Is Null Or Column4 = @Parameter4) And
    (@Parameter5 Is Null Or Column5 = @Parameter5)
```

But obviously that won't work. Is there any way of doing something like this, or am I thinking about it in completely the wrong way?

Comment: I think making complex assertions here may be counter intuitive: what about having two different procedures and calling one or the other depending on the conditions?

Comment: Handle that in your program logic and not in SQL. There is nothing wrong with having more than one query. Or you could build the query in your logic.

Comment: You do know that OR will be applied last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cumbersome solution would be something like this:

```
@Parameter1 int = null,
@Parameter2 int = null,
@Parameter3 int = null,
@Parameter4 int = null,
@Parameter5 int = null,
@UseOR bit = False

Select * From Table
Where 
    (@Parameter1 Is Null Or Column1 = @Parameter1) And
    (@Parameter2 Is Null Or Column2 = @Parameter2) And
    (
        (
            @UseOR = 0 AND
            ((@Parameter3 Is Null Or Column3 = @Parameter3) And (@Parameter4 Is Null Or Column4 = @Parameter4))
        ) OR 
        (
            @UseOR = 1 AND
            ((@Parameter3 Is Null Or Column3 = @Parameter3) OR (@Parameter4 Is Null Or Column4 = @Parameter4))
        )
    ) And
    (@Parameter5 Is Null Or Column5 = @Parameter5)
```

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, as it is what I asked for. However, I think you are all right and I should just use two seperate queries.